# Accessing atomic property of a custom object many times

Tags: java, optimization

Which function is faster (p is atomic public int property of MyObject):

```
public static boolean check(MyObject o1, List<MyObject> list) {

    int p = o1.p;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
        MyObject o = list.get(i);
        if (o.p < p) return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

or

```
public static boolean check(MyObject o1, List<MyObject> list) {

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
        MyObject o = list.get(i);
        if (o.p < o1.p) return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

So by using the local variable p we cache the object property call or it is done inline by the compiler optimization?

Comment: I did not know there was an `atomic` keyword in Java, and I can't find any reference in Google

Comment: Maybe she means she's using an `AtomicInteger`?  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html

Comment: Clearly the second option can't be faster than the second.  So the question is only "is this at least as fast."  The answer is "maybe."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short Answer: It depends

Slightly longer Answer: It depends on the compiler, the VM and the settings of your VM.

Background: Using the HotSpot VM (most common flavor) in server mode will make both variants equal since the VM does loop invariant hoisting in server mode. In client mode this *may be done*, *may not be done* or even *may be done later* if the VM considers it worthy of optimisations.

[Loop invariant hoisting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler_optimization#Loop_optimizations) is one of the loop optimisation, that is implemented into most modern compilers (or in the case of Java, VMs). As for the code generated by javac: Without further optimization done by the VM your first code sniplet will perfom faster.

```
public static boolean check(Test$MyObject, java.util.List);
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   getfield        #7; //Field Test$MyObject.p:I
   4:   istore_2
   5:   iconst_0
   6:   istore_3
   7:   iload_3
   8:   ldc     #4; //int 1000000
   10:  if_icmpge       42
   13:  aload_1
   14:  iload_3
   15:  invokeinterface #11,  2; //InterfaceMethod java/util/List.get:(I)Ljava/lang/Object;
   20:  checkcast       #5; //class Test$MyObject
   23:  astore  4
   25:  aload   4
   27:  getfield        #7; //Field Test$MyObject.p:I
   30:  iload_2
   31:  if_icmpge       36
   34:  iconst_0
   35:  ireturn
   36:  iinc    3, 1
   39:  goto    7
   42:  iconst_1
   43:  ireturn
```

--

```
public static boolean check(Test$MyObject, java.util.List);
  Code:
   0:   iconst_0
   1:   istore_2
   2:   iload_2
   3:   ldc     #4; //int 1000000
   5:   if_icmpge       38
   8:   aload_1
   9:   iload_2
   10:  invokeinterface #11,  2; //InterfaceMethod java/util/List.get:(I)Ljava/lang/Object;
   15:  checkcast       #5; //class Test$MyObject
   18:  astore_3
   19:  aload_3
   20:  getfield        #7; //Field Test$MyObject.p:I
   23:  aload_0
   24:  getfield        #7; //Field Test$MyObject.p:I
   27:  if_icmpge       32
   30:  iconst_0
   31:  ireturn
   32:  iinc    2, 1
   35:  goto    2
   38:  iconst_1
   39:  ireturn
```

As you can see, the getfield operation from line 20 in the second example lies in line 1 in the first and is outside of the loop (lines 7 to 39 in variant 1 and lines 2 to 35 in variant 2) and is therefore only executed ondced instead of 1000000 times.

Answer (score 2):

The `javac` compiler does next to no optimisations.

The JIT however can optimise the code significantly including storing fields in registers,

Comment: Eclipse's compiler (from IBM) produces almost the same code as Oracle HotSpot's compiler.

Answer (score 2):

Although not directly on topic, you can improve style and achieve more *constent* speed by using a "foreach" loop:

```
for (MyObject o : list) {
    if (o.p < o1.p) return false;
}
```

Results of tests switching to foreach:

- `ArrayList` 10% slower
- `LinkedList` 700 times faster with just 100000 elements

Comment: For each loop is the slowest loop ever possible :)

Comment: This is very much on topic IMHO. If the caller passes a LinkedList, it will speed up execution time by a factor of about 200000 (the foreach loop uses an iterator, where fetching the next element is O(1). get(i) will traverse the list for every element read.

Comment: I just did a simple test on `ArrayList`, and you're right! But it's only about 10% slower. It certainly *looks* nicer :) But not all `Lists` will be faster in the raw form. At least you're guaranteed fairly constant performance